# Error using Collections.sort

Tags: java, sorting, oop, arraylist, collections

I'm trying to sort the end times of events. In my Application class endTime which is located in my Event class, is defined by the hour and minute in my Time class.

Added `implements Comparable<Event>` to my event class, although I get `The type Event must implement the inherited abstract method Comparable<Event>.compareTo(Event)`.I tried the quick fix `add unimplemented methods` and found little success.

```
ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList <Event>();

Time endTime = new Time((startTime.getHour()), (startTime.getMinute() + duration));
```

In my time class I use compareTo

```
public class Time implements Comparable<Time> {

@Override
public int compareTo(Time time){
    if (this.getHour() > time.getHour())
        return 1;
    else if (this.getHour() == time.getHour())
        return 0;
    else 
        return -1;
}
```

When I try to sort the arrayList in my application class I get

```
The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Event>)

                Collections.sort(events);
```

Comment: Does `Event` implement `Comparable<Event>`? (Not clear why the `Time` class is relevant)

Comment: Should my Event implement `Comparable<Event>` ? It doesn't have a `compareTo` in it. The `compareTo` is located in the `Time` class.

Comment: Yes. How else would `Collections.sort` know how to compare instances of it? It doesn't know to sort on `endTime` unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 0):

The Collections.sort() is:

```
      public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
            list.sort(null);
      }
```

so,should make the Event implements comparable instead of Time.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to sort *collection of events* based on *event time* then Event class should implement Comparable interface and use compare method from Time class.

Just add implementation of Comparable interface to Event class and compare Time objects inside it:

```
public class Event implements Comparable<Event>{

    //removed fields and methods

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Event event){
       return this.getTime().compareTo(event.getTime());
    }

}
```